# Saving logged in user info in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to update **planTable** model with the current logged in user automatically. In my **planForm** form, I have excluded "user" field.

These are my code snippets.

**views.py**

```
def createPlan(request):
    
    form = planForm
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = planForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            
            form.save()
            
            return redirect('index')
    
    
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'workoutapp/create_plan.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='/register_user/')
def myPlan(request):
        
    my_plan = planTable.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    print('user : ', request.user)
    #print('data : ', my_plan)
    context = {'my_plan':my_plan}
    return render(request, 'workoutapp/my_plan.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class planTable(models.Model):
    
    DAYS = (
        ("sunday", "sunday"),
        ("monday", "monday"),
        ("tuesday", "tuesday"),
    )
    
    day = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10, choices=DAYS)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(workoutTable, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(itemTable, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.day
```

**forms.py**

```
class planForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = planTable 
        fields = 'day', 'category', 'exercise'
```

**create_plan.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form}}



    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

My requirement is that when the logged in user clicks on submit button, the fields in **planTable** should get populated with the values. But after logged in user click on submit button, only **day**, **category** and **exercise** gets populated, the user field stays blank. Is there any way for the user field to get populated depending on the logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validate the form without a user then set it:

```
def createPlan(request):
    
    form = planForm
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = planForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            plan = form.save(commit=False)
            plan.user = request.user
            plan.save()
            return redirect('index')
    
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'workoutapp/create_plan.html', context)
```